# Subgroups of order $21$ of symmetric group $S_{10}$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I am seeking the subgroups of order $21$ of symmetric group $S_{10}$ .

I find one which the subgroup $H$ generated by two elements $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)$ and $(8,9,10)$. Since their order $7$ and $3$ respectively, so the order of the subgroup $H$ generated by these two is $\operatorname{lcm}(7,3)=21$.

Are there any other subgroups of order $21$ which are not of this form ?

Comment: There is a subgroup of $S_7$ of order $21$.

Comment: If there is a subgroup of order 21 of S_7 then there will be similar subgroup of S_10. Can you tell that ?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: There are three conjugacy classes of subgroups of order $10$ in $S_{10}$, one cyclic (the one you found) and two nonabelian.

Comment: Order $10$? @DerekHolt

Comment: @citadel I meant order $21$ of course (or possibly using base $21$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll concretize the comments.

If $a=(1234567)$ and $b=(235)(467)$, then
$$
bab^{-1}=a^2.
$$
It follows that if $H=\langle a,b\rangle$, then $|H|=21$.
And obviously $H<S_7<S_{10}$.

Note that the permutations  here are multiplied from right to left, i.e. $(12)(23)=(123)$.

Comment: Is there any need of bab^(-1) = a^2 here ?

Comment: @tiwari_at183, that means that the subgroup is non-abelian, then other than what you have found already.